# Best way to append byte 0 to the end of byte array in Golang

Tags: go, byte

What is the best way to append byte 0 to the end of byte array in Golang?

I have tried these solution:

```
    data := []byte(location)
    empty := []byte{0}
    locationBytes = append(data, empty[0])
    //locationBytes = append(data, ""...) // not working
```

The scenario in my case is to transfer string to byte array. But byte array doesn't have `\0` as a terminate symbol to the end.

Comment: Have you tried `bytes = append(bytes, 0)`? And use the `%q` verb int a print if you want to see non-readable characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly append 0 in a byte array, you don't need to create empty := []byte{0}

```
data := []byte(location)
locationBytes = append(data, 0)
```